# How can I create a wallpaper slideshow with a different image per screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-background, slideshow

I would like to create a wallpaper slideshow on Ubuntu Focal (20) but I have a multi-monitor setup and would like to have a different image on each screen, all rotating at the same interval, similar to what is available on Win10.

I am aware that you can use Shotwell to create a slideshow (what I am currently using) but it displays the same picture on each screen.
I've heard about solutions like nitrogen that generate a multi-monitor background but it's not a slideshow (and it's not flexible, I am frequently changing monitors).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/07/hydrapaper-different-wallpaper-each-monitor-ubuntu/ Hydrapaper can do multiple monitors with different wallpapers.  Don't know about a slideshow type though.

Comment: @Terrance thanks for the suggestion, but it does not look like HydraPaper can make slideshows.

Comment: I actually have not seen anything for GNOME that can do slideshow or automatic wallpaper change.   However, other Desktops like Xubuntu actually comes with it built in.

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm still looking. It's the one downside of Gnome :(

Comment: @Richard No I haven't found anything, but to be honest I've not been actively searching :/

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it exists for Gnome and they don't plan on making it. At least the app Variety is an easy to use slideshow, it just shows the same image on every monitor. Shotwell is bad because it tries to copy all your wallpaper, wasting GBs.